# Mini split minimal pipe length

Tags: hvac, air-conditioning, mini-split

Quick question - my LG mini split manual says that I need a minimal of 10’ from the indoor unit to the branch box.  My question is do I include the 1-1.5’ piping that comes with the indoor evaporator? Or do I measure from flare to flare?  Seems to me I need 10 minus the length included so I just need to add 9 or so, but I heard otherwise elsewhere.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would call the support line to verify the length. The unit is precharged with refrigerant and too short a line set will cause an overcharge condition.
Overcharge can cause icing of the system and shorten the service life.

Worst case, make a loop close to the compressor. A loop helps reduce vibrations transmitted through the line set when the length is short.